# jquery dialog not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cross-browser, incompatibility

Why is that jquery dialog does not work in firefox? this is working in IE very well.I used jqueryblockui.js pug-in.

```
function showConfirmation(progTit, msgText, msgIcon, msgHideIcon) {
    var tblMsg;

    tblMsg = '<table width="310" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height=113px >' +
'<tr style="background-color:#3a3a3a;">' +
    '<td style="width:30px;" valign="middle"></td>' +
    '<td style="height:2px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff; font-style:bold;">' + progTit + '</td>' +
    '<td height="1px">' +
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.unblockUI();"><img src="' + msgHideIcon + '" alt="Hide" title="Hide" style="border:0;"/></a>' +
    '</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
'<td style="width:30px;" valign="middle"></td>' +
'<td style="text-align:center;"><img src="' + msgIcon + '"/>&nbsp; ' + msgText + '</td>' +
'<td style="width:30px;" align="center" valign="middle"></td>' +
'</tr>' +
'</table>';


    $('#divConfirm').html(tblMsg);

    $.blockUI({ message: $('#divConfirm') });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this this one :)

```
<script>
function showConfirmation(progTit, msgText, msgIcon, msgHideIcon) {
    var tblMsg = '<table width="310" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height=113px >'
               +      '<tr style="background-color:#3a3a3a;">'
               +           '<td style="width:30px;" valign="middle"></td>'
               +           '<td style="height:2px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff; font-style:bold;">' + progTit + '</td>'
               +           '<td height="1px">'
               +              '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.unblockUI();"><img src="' + msgHideIcon + '" alt="Hide" title="Hide" style="border:0;"/></a>'
               +           '</td>'
               +       '</tr>'
               +       '<tr>'
               +          '<td style="width:30px;" valign="middle"></td>'
               +          '<td style="text-align:center;"><img src="' + msgIcon + '"/>&nbsp; ' + msgText + '</td>'
               +          '<td style="width:30px;" align="center" valign="middle"></td>'
               +       '</tr>'
               + '</table>';

    $.blockUI({ message: tblMsg });
}
$(function() {
    showConfirmation('Title', 'Hello World', '', '')
});
</script>
```